# Graph constructed using graphx is not getting broadcast-ed properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I created a graph using graphx and now I need to extract sub-graphs from the original graph. users_graph is an RDD which has a sub-graph indexed to a user. The problem is that these sub-graphs are not getting computed. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException exception when I try to operate on these sub-graphs.

```
class VertexProperty(val id:Long) extends Serializable
case class User(val userId:Long, var offset:Int, val userCode:String, val Name:String, val Surname:String, val organizational_unit:String, val UME:String, val person_type:String, val SOD_HIGH:String, val SOD_MEDIUM:String, val SOD_LOW:String, val Under_mitigated:String) extends VertexProperty(userId)
case class Account(val accountId:Long, var offset:Int, val userCode:String, val userId:String, val account_creation_date:String, var disabled:String, var forcechangepwd:String, var pwdlife:String, var numberloginerror:String, var lastchangepwd:String, var lastlogin:String, var lastwronglogin:String, var state:String, var expire:String, var last_cert_time:String, var creation_date:String, var creation_user:String,var challenge_counter:String, var challenge_failed_attempt:String) extends VertexProperty(accountId) //Check if userCode is actually the code in this example.
case class Application(var applicationId:Long, var offset:Int, var Name:String, var Description:String, var Target:String, var Owner:String, var Ownercode:String, var Creation_date:String, var Creation_user:String) extends VertexProperty(applicationId)
case class Entitlement(val entitlementId:Long, var offset:Int, val Name:String, var Code:String, var Description:String, var Type:String, var Application:String, var Administrative:String, var Parent_ID:String, var Owner_code:String, var Scope_type:String, var Business_name:String, var Business_policy:String, var SOD_high:String, var SOD_medium:String, var SOD_low:String) extends VertexProperty(entitlementId)

/*
Some code for computing vertexRDD and edges
*/    

val graph: Graph[VertexProperty,String] = Graph(vertexRDD, edges, new VertexProperty(-1))
val triplets = graph.triplets
val temp = triplets.map(t => t.attr)
val distinct_users = temp.distinct.filter(t => t != "NULL")

var bcast_graph = sc.broadcast(graph)
val users_graph = distinct_users.map(du => du -> bcast_graph.value.subgraph(epred = t => t.attr == du))
```

Comment: Also, I tried this,

    val user_graph = bcast_graph.value.subgraph(epred = t => t.attr == "273") // "273" is a user-id.

And this gives me the desired output. I don't know why I am not getting output while using map function.

Comment: I don't get why you are broadcasting. A `Graph`, since it is composed of `RDDs`, is parallelized by its nature. What do you think you are accomplishing with `sc.broadcast(graph)` ?

Comment: I want to use the constructed graph in map function. Hence, I need to broadcast it before using there. Am I missing on something?

Comment: Yes, you can't broadcast a `Graph`

Comment: I tried removing broadcast for graph and ran the following code. val users_graph = distinct_users.map(du => du -> graph.subgraph(epred = t => t.attr == du)) . It is giving me error though.

Comment: Yeah, I realized what you are trying to do. See my fuller answer in a second or three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you can't `broadcast` a `Graph` because it contains an `RDD` (actually a couple of them). And you cannot use a `Graph`in a `map` function on an `RDD` because it is composed of `RDDs`.

Like I said, it's a long story why you cannot do either of those -- and they're really 2 sides of the same coin. It's the same issue you are up against either way.

Spark is built on a master / slave concept. It's in the master's memory space where `RDDs` and the meta-actions associated with them are defined. But the code -- the `...` inside `map(...)` -- gets executed on the slaves (called executors). Your map code cannot run inside the executors when you refer to a different `RDD` in any way -- and `broadcast` is never going to help, because the `RDD` references can only exist in the master.

What can you do instead? You have two options:

1. Collect the data you need using `collect()`, and either `broadcast` that data or just refer to it inside of your `map` code. `collect()` pulls all the data into the master, but most importantly for your issue it means that you can now refer to the data without using an `RDD` reference, so you can ship the collected data out to your executors -- either by using `broadcast` or just by referring to them in your `map(...)` code (Spark will ship copies of the data to your executors). Which of these works -- or whether either will -- depends on your data size, speed expectations, etc.
2. Use `RDD.join()` or `RDD.cogroup()` to work on the two `Graphs` at the same time.

Both of these are complicated by the fact that you are working on a higher-order structure -- a GraphX `Graph`. You are going to have to work on the separate `Graph.vertices` and `Graph.edges` `RDDs` separately, do your `collect()` or `join()` and then re-build the final `Graph` by stitching together the appropriate `RDDs`.

Comment: Explains everything!

Comment: I tried collecting EdgeTriplets and then broadcasting it. It gives me errors though. Kindly check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710483/edgetriplets-are-not-getting-broadcast-ed-properly